# JButton Invisible/Visible if arguments correct

Tags: java, jbutton

I am begginer in Java and was reading all topics for JButton, but didn't understand, how to make this work.:

I have got class:

```
class CarMain{
 public  int Money;
 public  int Boxes;
 public  int MoneyClicks;
 public  int BoxesClicks;
 public  int PlayerLevel;
 public  int BoxLevel;
```

}

And JButtons(Over 200 hundred) For Example:

```
JButton jbtnPartsLv2 = new JButton("Open");
```

I Added Listener:

```
jbtnPartsLv2.addActionListener(this);
```

And Set:

```
jbtnPartsLv2.setEnabled(false);
```

My thought is that, If statement correct, it sets button clickable :

```
private void Check() {
if(CarMain.PlayerLevel >=2){
                jbtnPartsLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnBuyBoxLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnBuyFrameLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnBuildCarLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellAccessoriesLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellBodyLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellBrakesLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellCoolingLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellElectronicsLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellEngineLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellExaustLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellFuelLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellInteriorLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellSteeringLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellSuspensionLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellTransmissionLv2.setEnabled(true);
                jbtnSellTiresLv2.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

}

I Started to build, GameLoop, but didn't end it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        private boolean GameLoop = false;
        public void run() {
            GameLoop = true;
            createAndShowGUI();
            while(GameLoop){
                Check();
            }
        }
```

ERROR, That I get : `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field jbtnPartsLv2`

Answer (score -1):

make check a static void like this.

```
public static void Check(){
if(CarMain.PlayerLevel >=2){
            jbtnPartsLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnBuyBoxLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnBuyFrameLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnBuildCarLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellAccessoriesLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellBodyLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellBrakesLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellCoolingLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellElectronicsLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellEngineLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellExaustLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellFuelLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellInteriorLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellSteeringLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellSuspensionLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellTransmissionLv2.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnSellTiresLv2.setEnabled(true);
        }
 }
```

Also make a static button like so

```
static JButton jbtnPartsLv2 = new JButton("Open");
```

Comment: Making things static - is bad idea, especially for Swing components. What if he wants several panels / dialogs with these buttons?